# Rails Invoicing App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create an invoice in rails. Invoice can have items and each item will have quantity, tax & price. It's a typical invoice we see everyday.

In order to create an invoice what is the best approach.

What is the common model for invoice and items?

I know Items will be a separate model. But how can we have one view for invoice, which creates both the invoice and items added to it?

What I mean is, Inside a new invoice page, there will be list of the clients, and list of the items , But here i'm not sure how to make the association when i create invoice. Is there any good example that i can follow ?

Please I'd appreciate some Help. Or even just a walk through of the steps i need to follow in order to accomplish that...

Here's my basic ERD

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a broad question, here's what I'd do:

```
#app/models/invoice.rb
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user

   has_many :line_items
   has_many :items, through: :line_items

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :line_items
end

#app/models/line_item.rb
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :invoice
  belongs_to :item
end

#app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :line_items
  has_many :invoices, through: :line_items
end
```

--

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :invoices
end
```

This will be the base level "invoice" association structure - your `clients`/`users` can be built on top of it.

Your routes etc can be as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :invoices

#app/controllers/invoices_controller.rb
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @invoice = current_user.invoices.new
      @invoice.line_items.build
   end

   def create
      @invoice = current_user.invoices.new invoice_params
      @invoice.save 
   end
end
```

Then your view will be something like this:

```
#app/views/invoices/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :line_items do |l| %>
     <%= f.text_field :quantity %>
     <%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This would create the corresponding `@invoice`, with which you'll be able to call as follows:

```
@user.invoices.first
```

Apart from this, I don't have anywhere enough specific information to help specifically

Comment: Thanks man for the feedback, and i like what you suggested so far. I'm gonna try this and will let you know once I get it working or if i'm having any issues( Hopefully Not). Cheers

Comment: Jus wondering about what should goes inside the the item table and the line_item table. I mean item_name price qty & ect . Like for my situation, i've sth like current_company and and to call the existing items i'd do sth like this current_company.items, so do i need to change to current_company.line_items ? I'm jus quite confused about item and line_item and what goes inside them.

Answer (score 0):

May I recommend using the [payday gem](https://github.com/commondream/payday)? I have created invoice models in the past applications and I'll tell you what, it can get pretty tricky sometimes depending on the type of application you're building. But the reason I like using this gem besides the convenience factor is that it can also render your invoices as a customizable PDF.

It makes adding items to the invoice a breeze as well, for example from their GitHub page:

```
invoice = Payday::Invoice.new(:invoice_number => 12)
invoice.line_items << Payday::LineItem.new(:price => 20, :quantity => 5, :description => "Pants")
invoice.line_items << Payday::LineItem.new(:price => 10, :quantity => 3, :description => "Shirts")
invoice.line_items << Payday::LineItem.new(:price => 5, :quantity => 200, :description => "Hats")
invoice.render_pdf_to_file("/path/to_file.pdf")
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :) i'm trying to build this without using lots of gems .